# Please help me get this equation part right

Tags: circuit-analysis, kirchhoffs-laws, mesh-analysis

[image]

Hello everyone, I am understanding the concept of mesh analysis and super meshes. In the Practice problem below, I am presented with a dependent current source and it lies between mesh 2 and mesh 3. Therefore, a super mesh will be utilized.  However, on my third equation circled in red, I keep getting the signs wrong. How do I get them right?

Comment: No, don't use a super-mesh. I hate them. And they aren't ever needed. Do you really have to use one?

Comment: Yes I have to understand this concept as it is part of the lecture

Comment: Just look at the direction in which the net current flows. Since the net current flows from left to right, which says that i3 is greater than i2. Hence, you should subtract i2 from i3. i2 is opposite in direction to i3.

Comment: supermesh is not any concept. It is just some 'trick' derived from KVL, KVL is the CONCEPT.

Comment: @Jonathan_the_seagull I have subtracted i2 from i3 but according to the answer from the book it is i3 - i2

Comment: @GreenLeaf21 What is i2 subtracted from i3?

Comment: i2-i3=15i1 which equates to the dependent source

Comment: @GreenLeaf21 No. i2 subtracted from i3 is i3-i2.

Comment: @Jonathan_the_seagull Ah for some reason I have been thinking hard a lot and thought the other way around. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The direction of the net current as indicated by the current controlled current source is in the direction of i3. i2 has a direction opposite to i3 in the middle arm. Since the direction of the net current and the direction of i3 is same, we can say that i3-i2 is equal to 15i1(which is the net current).